# What does the resultant matrix of Homography denote?

Tags: computer-vision

I have 2 frames of shaky video. I applied homography on all the inliers points. Now the resultant matrix that i get for different frames are like this

```
0.2711   -0.0036    0.853
-0.0002    0.2719   -0.2247
0.0000   -0.0000    0.2704


0.4787   -0.0061    0.5514
0.0007    0.4798   -0.0799
0.0000   -0.0000    0.4797
```

What are those similar values in the diagonal and how can I retrieve the translation component from this matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the following observation: a homography matrix is only defined up to scale. This means that if you divide or multiply all the matrix coefficients by the same number, you obtain a matrix that represent the same geometrical transformation. This is because, in order to apply the homography to a point at coordinates (x, y), you multiply its matrix H on the right by the column vector [x, y, 1]' (here I use the apostrophe symbol to denote transposition), and then divide the result H * x = [u, v, w]' by the third component w. Therefore, if instead of H you use a scaled matrix (s * H), you end up with [s*u, s*v, s*w], which represents the same 2D point.

So, to understand what is going on with your matrices, start by dividing both of them by their  bottom-right component:

```
octave:1> a = [ 
> 0.2711   -0.0036    0.853
> -0.0002    0.2719   -0.2247
> 0.0000   -0.0000    0.2704
> ];
octave:2> b=[
> 0.4787   -0.0061    0.5514
> 0.0007    0.4798   -0.0799
> 0.0000   -0.0000    0.4797];
octave:3> a/a(3,3)
ans =
1.00259  -0.01331   3.15459
-0.00074   1.00555  -0.83099
0.00000  -0.00000   1.00000
octave:4> b/b(3,3)
ans =
0.99792  -0.01272   1.14947
0.00146   1.00021  -0.16656
0.00000  -0.00000   1.00000
```

Now suppose, for the moment, that the third column elements in both matrices were [0, 0, 1]'. Then the effect of applying it to any point (x, y) would be to move it by approx 1/100 units (say, pixels). Basically, not changing it by much. 
Plugging back the actual values for the third column shows that both matrices are, essentially, translating the whole images by constant amounts.

So, in conclusion, having equal values on the diagonals, and very small values at indices (1,2) and (2,1), means that these homographies are both (essentially) pure translations.

Answer (score 0):

Various transformations involve all elementary operations such as addition, multiplication, division, and addition of a constant. Only the first two can be modeled by regular matrix multiplication. Note that addition of a constant and, in case of a Homography, division is impossible to represent with matrix multiplication in 2D. Adding a third coordinate  (that is converting points to homogeneous representation) solves this problem. For example, if you want to add constant 5 to x you can do this like this

```
1 0 5     x     x+5   
0 1 0  *  y  =  y  
          1
```

Note that matrix is 2x3, not 2x2 and coordinates have three numbers though they represent 2D points. Also, the last transition is converting back from homogeneous to Euclidian representation. Thus two results are achieved: all operations (multiplication, division, addition of variables and additions of constants) can be represented by matrix multiplication; second, we can chain multiple operations (via multiplying their matrices) and still have only a single matrix as the result (of matrix multiplication).

Ok, now let’s explain Homography. Homography is better to consider in the context of the whole family of transformation moving from simple ones to complex ones. In other words, it is easier to understand the meaning of Homography coefficients by comparing them to the meaning of coefficients of simpler Euclidean, Similarity and Affine transforms. The Euclidwan transformation is the simplest and represents a rigid rotation and translation in space (note that matrix is 2x3). For 2D case,

```
cos(a) -sin(a) Tx 

sin(a)  cos(a) Ty
```

Similarity adds scaling to the rotation coefficients. So now the matrix looks like this:

```
Scl*cos(a) -scl*sin(a) Tx 

Scl*sin(a)  scl*cos(a) Ty
```

Affiliate transformation adds shearing so the rotation coefficients become unrestricted:

```
a11 a12 Tx  

a21 a22 Ty
```

Homography adds another row that divides the output x and y (see how we explained the division during the transition form homogeneous to Euclidean coordinates above) and thus introduces **projectivity** or non uniform scaling that is a function of point coordinates. This is better understood by looking at the transition to Euclidean coordinates.

```
   a11 a12 Tx    x     a11*x+a12*y+Tx    (a11*x+a12*y+Tx)/(a32*x+a32*y+a33)

   a21 a22 Ty *  y =   a21*x+a22*y+Ty -> (a21*x+a22*y+Ty)/(a32*x+a32*y+a33)

   a31 a32 a33   1     a32*x+a32*y+a33
```

Thus homography has an extra row compared to other transformations such as affine or similarity. This extra row allows to scale objects depending on their coordinates which is how projectivity is formed.

Finally, speaking of your numbers:

```
0.4787   -0.0061    0.5514  
0.0007    0.4798   -0.0799  
0.0000   -0.0000    0.4797
```

**This is not homography!**. Just look at the last row and you will see that the first two coefficients are 0 thus there is no projectivity. Since a11=a22 **this is not even an Affine** transformation. This is rather a similarity transform. The translation is
Tx=0.5514/0.4797 and Ty=-0.0799/0.4797